# Where did the type ahead menu for CSS SLDS classes go?

Tags: css, slds, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

In VSCode, there used to be a type ahead window with suggestions of SLDS classes when you start to create one. This menu no longer appears for me.

For example when I would type `<span class="slds-` a window with suggestions of slds classes would appear. I've included a screenshot below.

I am using the latest version (1.51) of VSCode on Windows 10. I tried updating SFDX, the Salesforce CLI extension, restarting the program and rebooting computer.

[image: slds type-ahead]

Comment: The intellisense feature if I remember stopped working automatically a while back, and now triggers with ctrl + space shortcut. :(

Comment: I use this http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/tools/validator/

Comment: @Raul this brings up a menu, but it is only classes that have already been used in the file, not the complete list of classes available.

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty I have the SLDS validator extension installed. It does not have any affect on whether this menu appears or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the specific version of the SLDS Validator extension. I had to install an old version of it (1.0.0). Then the type-ahead menu came back.

The current version I was on was not working (1.4.0).

Answer (score 0):

In the settings.json there is a setting:

`"editor.quickSuggestions"`

At first I thought this solved the problem, but then I realized it was only showing suggestions for slds classes that were already present in the file.